# My character's horizontal movement is stopping me from using rigidBody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right) or any horizontal axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep trying to Addforce to the left or right but nothing happens. This happened to me in another game before. I just figured out what it was

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * moveX * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y);
```

Here, I'm setting the velocity to 0 if I'm not moving (moveX is `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` )
How do I AddForce horizontally while not having to disable my normal movement? I know I can use transform.Translate but I'd prefer using rb.velocity for now.

Comment: Well you either use forces or control directly the velocity .. you can't really mix them both ... and you don't want to do anything via Transform when a Rigidbody is involved

Answer (score 0):

With the add force function, link to unity docs below.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this several times but

- if you are using `AddForce` what you can do is either make sure to add a good amount of speed value to it

  ```
  rb.AddForce(inputMove.x * speed);
  ```
- if you are using `Time.deltatime` or don't use time at
  all...something like:

  ```
  rb.AddForce(inputMove.x * Time.deltatime * speed);
  ```